# UserWarning on Django website for Raven client

Tags: python, django

I am running Django based on Django Cookiecutter. 
Once I built (`docker-compose build`)  and started (`docker-compose up`) everything seems to work just fine.

However when I try to open the website I get an `Internal server error`.

In the log there is an error messaage `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/raven/conf/remote.py:88: UserWarning: Transport selection via DSN is deprecated. You should explicitly pass the transport class to Client() instead.`

I can't really find any information except for that I have to add `RAVEN_CONFIG = {}` to my settings.

This is my current settings file:

## base.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import environ

ROOT_DIR = environ.Path(__file__) - 3  # (oz_m_de/config/settings/base.py - 3 = oz_m_de/)
APPS_DIR = ROOT_DIR.path('oz_m_de')

env = environ.Env()

READ_DOT_ENV_FILE = env.bool('DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE', default=False)

if READ_DOT_ENV_FILE:
    env_file = str(ROOT_DIR.path('.env'))
    print('Loading : {}'.format(env_file))
    env.read_env(env_file)
    print('The .env file has been loaded. See base.py for more information')

DJANGO_APPS = [
    # Default Django apps:
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Useful template tags:
    # 'django.contrib.humanize',

    # Admin
    'django.contrib.admin',
]
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'crispy_forms',  # Form layouts
    'allauth',  # registration
    'allauth.account',  # registration
    'allauth.socialaccount',  # registration
]

LOCAL_APPS = [
    'oz_m_de.users.apps.UsersConfig',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

## production.py

Since I do not have an SSL certificate yet this is all turned off.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from boto.s3.connection import OrdinaryCallingFormat
from django.utils import six

import logging
from .base import *  # noqa

SECRET_KEY = env('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')

# SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

INSTALLED_APPS += ['raven.contrib.django.raven_compat', ]
RAVEN_MIDDLEWARE = ['raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.middleware.SentryResponseErrorIdMiddleware']
MIDDLEWARE = RAVEN_MIDDLEWARE + MIDDLEWARE

# SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 60
# SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = env.bool('DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS', default=True)
# SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = env.bool('DJANGO_SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF', default=True)
# SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
# SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
# SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
# SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = env.bool('DJANGO_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT', default=True)
# CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
# CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
# X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["foo.de", "123.123.123.123"]    
INSTALLED_APPS += ['gunicorn', ]

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = env('DJANGO_DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL', default='foo.de <noreply@foo.de>')
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = env('DJANGO_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX', default='[oz-m.de]')
SERVER_EMAIL = env('DJANGO_SERVER_EMAIL', default=DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL)

INSTALLED_APPS += ['anymail', ]
ANYMAIL = {
    'MAILGUN_API_KEY': env('DJANGO_MAILGUN_API_KEY'),
    'MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN': env('MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN')
}
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'anymail.backends.mailgun.MailgunBackend'    

# Sentry Configuration
SENTRY_DSN = env('DJANGO_SENTRY_DSN')
SENTRY_CLIENT = env('DJANGO_SENTRY_CLIENT', default='raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.DjangoClient')
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'root': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'handlers': ['sentry', ],
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s '
                      '%(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'handlers': ['console', ],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'raven': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console', ],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'sentry.errors': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console', ],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.security.DisallowedHost': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'handlers': ['console', 'sentry', ],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
SENTRY_CELERY_LOGLEVEL = env.int('DJANGO_SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL', logging.INFO)
RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'CELERY_LOGLEVEL': env.int('DJANGO_SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL', logging.INFO),
    'DSN': SENTRY_DSN
}
```